# Grab the integer after one of multiple string matches

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, grep

I want to get the battery voltage using

```
dumpsys battery
```

The output is something line this

```
Current Battery Service state:
  AC powered: false
  USB powered: false
  Wireless powered: false
  Max charging current: 0
  Max charging voltage: 0
  Charge counter: 2208619
  Overload: false
  USB overheat: false
  Extension: 0
  PowerJacketExist: false
  PowerJacketStatus: 0
  PowerJacketLevel: 0
  PluginStatus: false
  Unsupport Charger: false
  status: 3
  health: 2
  present: true
  level: 71
  scale: 100
  voltage: 4008
  temperature: 340
  technology: Li-ion
  mLedLogType: -1
  CutoffVoltage: 0
```

I only need the 4008 (this value can change) after "voltage:"
I tried this grep method but It didn't work I guess because there are multiple matches

```
dumpsys battery | grep voltage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following once. This should print all occurrences of string `voltage:`'s value.

```
awk '/^ +voltage:/ && $NF!=0{print $NF}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
your_command | awk '/^ +voltage:/ && $NF!=0{print $NF}'
```

OR in case you DO NOT want any zero value of voltage then try following.

```
awk '/^ +voltage:/ && $NF!=0{print $NF}' Input_file
```

OR in case you want 2nd occurrence of voltage string then try following.

```
awk '/^ +voltage:/ && ++count==2{print $NF}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code too now.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program here.
/^ +voltage:/{       ##Checking condition if a line consist string voltage: then do following.
  print $NF       ##This statement will be execute ONLY when previous condition is TRUE and it will print last field value here.
}'  Input_file    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***2nd Solution:*** Adding solution using `sed` command too now.

```
sed -n '/^ +voltage:/s/.*: //p' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
your_command | sed -n '/^ +voltage:/s/.*: //p'
```

Comment: The first solution output is
0
4000

And he second one gives
0
4000
340

Comment: Could you please show how only extract the voltage "4000" which seems to always be second value and put it in a variable

Comment: @ranger003, you mean it should be always 2nd match or string `voltage`? or it should NOT catch any ZERO value please clarify it once?

Comment: `awk '$1=="voltage:"{print $2}'`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 you don't discriminate the other match "Max charging voltage:"

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Exactly either always the 2nd match or the non-zero value both would do the jobe

Comment: @karakfa, sure sir will add it now thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @ranger003, check my EDITED (OR) solutions now and let me know?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Working perfectly as expected thank you guys for your precious time.

Comment: @ranger003, actually karfka sir corrected me, so I have changed matched condition from checking ONLY string `Voltage` to `/^ +voltage:/` only string `Voltage` will match `Max charging voltage` also which I believe we don't want. You can change conditions accordingly too. Also you could up-vote any helpful answers too for anyone on SO, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PCRE and positive lookbehind, if your `grep` supports it:

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=^  voltage: ).*" file 
4008
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'(^|:) *' '{f[$2]=$3} END{print f["voltage"]}' file
4008

$ awk -F'(^|:) *' '{f[$2]=$3} END{print f["Max charging voltage"]}' file
0

$ awk -F'(^|:) *' '{f[$2]=$3} END{print f["status"], f["health"], f["scale"]}' file
3 2 100
```

or to create a CSV of all fields (e.g. for import into Excel):

```
$ awk -F'(^|:) *' -v OFS=',' '
{ keys[NR]=$2; vals[$2]=$3 }
END {
    for (i=2; i<=NR; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", keys[i], (i<NR ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for (i=2; i<=NR; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", vals[keys[i]], (i<NR ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
' file
AC powered,USB powered,Wireless powered,Max charging current,Max charging voltage,Charge counter,Overload,USB overheat,Extension,PowerJacketExist,PowerJacketStatus,PowerJacketLevel,PluginStatus,Unsupport Charger,status,health,present,level,scale,voltage,temperature,technology,mLedLogType,CutoffVoltage
false,false,false,0,0,2208619,false,false,0,false,0,0,false,false,3,2,true,71,100,4008,340,Li-ion,-1,0
```